# How can I put a file upload form into my Pyramid app?

Tags: python, file-upload, pyramid

I am going through of [this tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/forms/file_uploads.html), but it is very confusing to me. First of all, in the `store_mp3_view` function, both `file` and `filename` are referenced when declaring `filename` and `input_file` (first two lines). From the form above, it seems that only `file` is an input (`filename` is never mentioned). Is `filename` automatically input?

Additionally, is the loop at the end writing the data to the output file necessary? For my application, I want to the upload process to start a separate script that parses data from the file. Do I have to first put the data into an output file and then parse that or was that just for the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From the form above it seems that only file is an input (filename is never mentioned). Is filename automatically input?

Correct, 'filename' attribute should be available anytime you upload a file from a form.

> Do I have to first put the data into an output file and then parse that or was that just for the example?

input_data is a file object, but you do not need to write input_data out to disk before parsing it, this example just happens to be writing it to disk.

Comment: thanks. You would think that they would mention that it was not necessary (the output loop) in the example.